# Count how many of each value from a field with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I've seen that question several times but I can't find out how to display the result.  I have a movie database and I would like the count of each genre of movie in my top menu in a single MySQL query so my menu would display like this:

```
Total Movies (300)
Drama (50)
Comedy (75)
Thriller (30)
...and so on...
```

I've found some MySQL query on this site but no one specify HOW to handle the counts after the SQL query.  Something like this would probably work:

```
select genre, count(*) from movies group by genre
```

But how do I display the count for each value afterwards?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Alias the count part so you have an easily accessible column name:

```
SELECT genre, count(*) AS nb_movies FROM movies GROUP BY genre
```

then you can access it like `$row['nb_movies']`.

Without the alias the aggregate column takes the name of the aggregate function call which produced it, so in your case it would be accessed like `$row['count(*)']`.

Comment: Ok 6 answers and almost the same for every one, still don't get it though, sorry... :(  what would give me the count of every different genre?  if I display it by using $row['nb_movies'], it will not give me the count for "Comedy" AND "Thriller" AND every other genre?  Do I absolutely need to do a WHILE to get the result like Ranjith suggested?

Comment: Yes you need to jsut loop through the results. I mean you could create a super complex query to give each genre/count as a column i think but thats silly. jsut loop. If you want the total for all genres combined than thats a different query OR snce you need to loop through and get to get the total for each genre any way you can jsut add them up as you go to get the grand total.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select genre, count(*) AS total from movies group by genre
```

Use total as your count for eg.

```
echo $result['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT genre, count(*) AS total_genre_movies FROM movies GROUP BY genre
```

Now you can access like `$result['total_genre_movies']`

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you alias the result of count(*)

```
select genre, 
       count(*) as total
  from movies 
 group by genre
```

Then you can access it as `$row['total']` when you fetch the result into `$row` in exactly the same way you'd reference `$row['genre']`

Answer (score 0):

```
   select genre, count(*) as genre_count from movies group by genre
```

Now you can access like $result['genre_count']

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$result = mysql_query("select genre, count(*) as genre_count from movies group by genre");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   $genre       = $row['genre'];
   $genre_count = $row['genre_count'];

}
```